# Need help installing Texpander

Tags: scripts

I'm following this guide - https://github.com/leehblue/texpander

I've installed xdotool, zenity and xclip and created the hotkey under keyboard settings. When I press the hotkey the zenity window pops-up.. so far, so good.

The problem is the zenity window is empty. I'm not sure where to create the ~/.texpander folder. I tried creating a folder called "texpander" in / and adding a .txt file to it, I tried creating a folder called "texpander" in the folder I moved the texpander.sh to.. but nothing so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure where to create the ~/.texpander folder.

What do you mean? "~" already tells you where: your home (the . means "hidden") and creating the directory will already create it where it is needed.

`mkdir ~/.texpander` is equal to `mkdir /home/$HOME/.texpander`.

Comment: Good to hear :)